# Create a List<XmlNode> from XML children, C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to create a `List<XmlNode>` from an `XmlDocument` that looks like this:

```
<Data>
  <Table>
    <node1>text</node1>
    <node2>text</node2>
    <node3>text</node3>
    <node4>text</node4>
  </Table>
 </Data>
```

I want to add all nodes under `<Table>` to the list and have list count = 4.

I have tried using `xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Data/Table")` but this seems to only return a list with one node with the whole table.

It is important that I return the specified `List<XmlNode>`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried using xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Data/Table") but this seems to only return a list with one node with the whole table.

This is correct behaviour. The XPath expression does select the `Table` node.
To select all of the children of the `Table` node, try

```
xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Data/Table/*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this XPath:

```
/Data/Table/*
```

it selects all child nodes of `Table`